# iseries - java external stored procedure returning result sets

Tags: java, stored-procedures, ibm-midrange

I am trying to build a SP to return a result set from a remote iSeries and I just can't seem to do it. I can return result sets from the local database, but not remote when I use JT400native.jar (also tried just the jt400.jar) to connect. Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

My SP is defined as this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.TEST   
(INOUT I INTEGER)                     
EXTERNAL NAME 'jproc1.returnTEST'  
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA                 
MODIFIES SQL DATA                    
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1                
LANGUAGE JAVA
```

Here the java code behind it which works, it will return result sets from the local database to the client (run sql scripts in iNavigator)

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.ibm.db2.app.*;

public class jproc1 {      
     public static void returnTEST(int[] myInputInteger, ResultSet[] myResultSet) throws Exception {
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
          Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
          String sql1 = "select TEST FROM MYLIB.TEST";
          myInputInteger[0] = 5;
          myResultSet[0]  = stmt1.executeQuery(sql1);
     }    
}
```

When I change the SP to to replace the connection with one to a remote iSeries it won't return the result set back to the client, it does however return the first out variable myInputInteger just fine. I believe I have everything setup correctly, I have all the Jars I need registered.  The important part here is that internally to the java program I get the result set from the remote iSeries, I can loop through it, count it, dump it to the IFS, it just won't pass it back to the client (Run SQL Scripts in iNavigator).

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.ibm.db2.app.*;

public class jproc1 {      
    public static void returnTEST(int[] myInputInteger, ResultSet[] myResultSet) throws Exception {
         Class.forName ("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver").newInstance ();
         String url  = "jdbc:as400://remoteiseries;naming=sql;prompt=false;user=myuser;password=mypass;translate binary=true";                
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);   
         Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
         String sql1 = "select TEST FROM MYLIB.TEST";
         myInputInteger[0] = 5
         myResultSet[0] = stmt1.executeQuery(sql1);
    } 
}
```

So, what am I missing?  I have tried a ton of variations including using DB2GENERAL parameter types (and corresponding changes to java program per chapter 7 on the DB2 UDB for iSeries manual).  No matter what I do it won't return those remote result sets back to client, and I don't get any errors.

TIA.

Comment: Can you clarify? It seems that you register your stored proc on "System A", you then connect to DB2 on "System A" and call the SP, but you want the SP to connect to DB2 on "System B" and return a result set from "System B" through "System A" and back to a client on some PC?

Comment: Hi,  the stored procedure is defined on system A which references a external java program that connects to system B.  the java program works, I retrieve the result set successfully in the java program (I can manipulate it, loop through it, write it to the database) but I can't return the result set back to the program calling the program.  I can only seem to do this when retrieving a result set from system A.  I think it's the way the result set is defined, when I pass system B result set back to calling program It seems to look null to it.

Comment: It gets confusing when you put `"(Run SQL Scripts in iNavigator)"` in your question. That directly implies that a 3rd system (a PC) is involved. The Java program can work fine on SystemA. Calling it as a SP after first connecting to DB2 on SystemA causes trouble due to the nested connection to a different instance of DB2. Does that sound like a correct understanding?

Comment: on an iSeries that's how you can natively call a stored procedure (run sql scripts in iNavigator) and get result sets back.  I don't believe it's a nested connection since I do get the result sets back to the java program, it just won't pass it back up to the caller.

Comment: I know that, except it's not "native"; iNav is a "remote" PC app. By starting a remote connection with iNav, it becomes nested when the logic routes to a second iSeries. Getting results from another iSeries with Java is easy, but getting the remote data into a client connection to the local database can be tricky. BTW, can you successfully call your local SP from any SQLRPGLE, SQLCBLLE or other native program and retrieve the remote result set?

Comment: Hi,  tried it from an embedded SQL C program, run from the command line.  When I connect locally in the java the C program gets the result sets back and prints them to a spool file.  When I change the java to query the remote database it doesn't pass the result set back to the C program. Again, I do get the results inside the java program and can dump them to the IFS, count em etc.  it just won't pass the result set back to the calling program. it will pass the record count back though (first output parm in java program) but that's an integer not a result set.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IBM i?

DB2 for IBM i has long been behind in its federation support...

Only recently, v7.1 TR 4, has it been possible to do a

```
insert into localtbl
  select * from remotetbl
```

But you still can't do

```
select * from localtbl join remotetbl using (key)
```

As the system only really supports one DB connection at a time in a job.

Interestingly, this [article](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg080812-printer01.html) gives a technique for using UDTF to get around the one connection limit.  I don't know enough about the internals to understand why a UDTF would work but an SP wouldn't.  But you might try changing from an SP to a UDTF.

Comment: Thanks!  It's OS 7.1,  I am only connecting to 1 database at a time, the issue is when I do it to a remote database, I can't pass the resultset back up back up to the client even though i can manipulate it in the java program itself.  So it's more of how the ResultSet datatype is defined maybe depending on the JDBC driver perhaps. I did notice those UDTF examples do a 'set' to the results from the remote database so they are not returned as null's but I can't figure out how to do it with a whole result set.  has anyone done this is MS SQL Server or Oracle?  Thanks!

Comment: @TarlCabot If my understanding above is correct, then a UDTF is the likely solution as Charles mentions. AFAIK, it runs in a separate job, so a second connection isn't really nested.

Comment: @TarlCabot See, e.g., [Accessing Multiple DB2 Relational Databases In A Single Query](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg080812-printer01.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I am only accessing 1 (one) database in a single query.  if I do a local one it returns result sets to the one calling the procedure, if I do a remote database the results sets do not get back to the calling procedure

Comment: @TarlCabot Two databases are being accessed. The SP is being accessed, and it's in DatabaseA. The SP is then attempting to access DatabaseB. Two databases in a single query. The "query" in this case is the CALL to the SP; and as with essentially all queries, it's attempting to generate a result set.

Comment: I disagree, the SP is being defined as an external procedure,  The external program does the query, and  it only accesses one DB in a single select statement.  I believe the restriction is accessing multiple databases in a single select statement (query).  But perhaps DB2 does think of it as that way, although I still think the issue is in the way the result set data type is defined as the query inside the external procedure actually works and returns values, it just won't pass it back up.

Comment: @TarlCabot `...the SP is being defined as an external procedure,` That's irrelevant. It makes zero difference if it's a SQL SP or a SP defined as EXTERNAL. Both run within the local database connection and within a single query. Nested within that single query, you attempt a second connection to a second database. You may disagree as much as you wish, but it won't change how it works. Another possibility might be using [SQL CLI in server mode](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cli/rzadpstartingservermode.htm?lang=en).